# Symfony2 - how to check if referer is external referer?

Tags: php, symfony, referer

I created a custom success_handler for my login, and here I want to check if the referer was external or not. How do I best do this?

```
$ref = $request->headers->get('Referer');
```

What is the best way to check if the referer is a local url (meaning: from within the symfony project) or external ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a current domain

```
$this->getRequest()->getHost()
```

And then match it via regex see here:
[Regex to match simple domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830411/regex-to-match-simple-domain)

Comment: I understood that, he wanted to check if project is external (IMHO external means from other domain?).

Comment: You could make the allowed hosts a parameter in parameters.yml and pass it along to the success_handler and check if $ref is in there