# Replace exact domain with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex for preg_replace.
He is replace all urls in given string.

Now I need replace only t.co urls. https://t.co/* and etc.

```
preg_replace('/\b((https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i', ' ', $text);
```

How to do it with preg_replace?

Comment: Will this work? `\bhttps?:\/\/t.co\S*`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript Reg Exp to match specific domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32730133/javascript-reg-exp-to-match-specific-domain-name)

Answer (score 1):

You could use preg_replace and matching the specific urls only:

```
\bhttps?://t\.co/\S*
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary
- `https?://` Match the protocol with optional s and `://`
- `t\.co` Match `t.co`
- `/\S*` Match `/` and 0+ non whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RTBoHT/1)

Example code

```
preg_replace('~\bhttps?://t\.co/\S*~i', ' ', $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient solution, but you might give [`preg_replace_callback()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) a try.

For example:

```
preg_replace_callback('/\b((https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i', function ($matches) {
    $url = $matches[0];
    if (preg_match('/^((https?:)?\/\/)?(www\.)?t\.co\b/i', $url)) {
        return ' ';
    } else {
        return $url;
    }
}, $text);
```